# How do I read an mp4 file directly into moviepy from S3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, moviepy

Any idea how to read an S3 mp4 file directly into moviepy?

I have tried,

```
import boto3
from io import BytesIO
from moviepy.editor import *

client = boto3.client('s3')
obj =  client.get_object(Bucket='some-bucket', Key='some-file')
VideoFileClip(BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()))
```

but I am getting,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/<path>/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/VideoFileClip.py", line 91, in __init__
fps_source=fps_source)
File "/<path>/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py", line 33, in __init__
fps_source)
File "/<path>/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py", line 243, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
is_GIF = filename.endswith('.gif')
AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

where path is my virtual environment

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, apologies in advance for the delay, but for anyone in the future looking for a potential solution, you can load videos with direct urls into VideoFileClip.

First, you'll need to generate a presigned url of the object in the bucket:

```
import boto3
import logging
def create_presigned_url(bucket_name, object_name, expiration=60):
"""Generate a presigned URL to share an S3 object

:param bucket_name: string
:param object_name: string
:param expiration: Time in seconds for the presigned URL to remain valid
:return: Presigned URL as string. If error, returns None.
"""

my_config = Config(
signature_version = 's3v4',)

# Generate a presigned URL for the S3 object
s3_client = boto3.client('s3',config=my_config)
try:
    response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                                Params={'Bucket':bucket_name,
                                                        'Key': object_name},
                                                ExpiresIn=expiration,
                                                )
except ClientError as e:
    logging.error(e)
    return None

# The response contains the presigned URL
return response
```

From there, you can then take that exact url into `VideoFileClip`:

```
import moviepy.editor as mpe
presignedurl=create_presigned_url(bucket,key)
vidclip=mpe.VideoFileClip(presignedurl)
```